# Grammatical reason why "using car" is incorrect

Tags: grammar

> Higher prices would not stop them from using car as their first choice of transportation

What's the grammatical reason that this sentence is incorrect, and "the car" or "cars" has to be said instead of simply "car"?

Comment: Who states that is it incorrect? It seems unusual to me but I would hesitate to call it incorrect.

Comment: All three ways are not normal regardless of correctness. I would use "**a car**." That is the common phrasing. (cars is pretty normal, but still not the best IMO)

Comment: [...] stop them using **a car or the car** etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is getting to how we express levels of abstraction and collective nouns and categories.

As the quote stands, the word "car" is referring to something non-specific and without quantity or difference. That is, it is referring to "car" in the abstract rather than in the specific.

Compare that with the following.

> Lower prices do not encourage them to use transit as their first choice.

> Lower prices do not encourage them to use a bus as their first choice.

> Lower prices do not encourage them to use the Bloor Subway as their first choice.

(Bloor is a street in Toronto, Canada. There is a subway that runs parallel to it.)

Here "transit" is an abstract thing. That is, it is a category of transportation.
"A bus" is a thing, but not a specific thing. It is more specific than transit, but still not specific  to a particular bus. "The Bloor Subway" is a specific thing.

Treating "car" as an abstract indefinite thing is unusual. I'm not sure whether it is grammatically correct or not. But it sounds very strange.  If you were in fact in a car you would be in a specific car. You would not ordinarily refer to this as "I am riding car." Where if you were on a bus you could say "I am taking transit." We don't usually use "car" as an abstract indefinite category in this way.

You might want to say something like "transportation by car" or some such rather than "car."  That is, you might choose some abstract phrase that indicates using a car but not a specific car.

Comment: +1, but note that in AmE we do **not** say "I am taking transit." Instead we say "I am taking the bus" (the train, the subway) even if we aren't specifying the specific transit line or the specific vehicle in use.

Comment: @randomhead same in British English.

Comment: Hmmm... In Canada, we do say "I am taking transit." English is quite a thing.   https://www.narcity.com/toronto/ontario-is-cutting-some-costs-when-taking-transit-heres-what-that-means-for-you

Comment: From an AmE perspective, I find "using car" completely unacceptable in all contexts.

Comment: In AmE or British, would you say "I am taking public transport?" Maybe the issue is the word transit? A brief search of some few British sources seems to indicate that "transit" is used nearly always for "crossing over" and similar. In the US, it seems like it is "mass transit" not just transit.

Answer (score -1):

At first look, it could seem like the word 'car' is missing an article or a possessive pronoun, for example, "*a* car", or "*their* car". In most contexts, the grammar of your example would be considered incorrect.

But, *depending on the wider context*, your example might be acceptable as it is.

It sounds like the quote could be referring to a large cohort of people - perhaps the results of a survey. They could have been asked how they travel - *by car, by bus, by train* etc. When we speak about these as modes of transport, they don't need an article. If 'car' didn't need would an article or determiner in the question, nor would it in the answer or any subsequent references to that answer, for example:

> Person A: What do you think is the best way to travel to work - by car, or by bus?
> Person B: Car.
> Person A: Why did you answer "car"?

In such a context, where you are speaking about the responses of a large, impersonal group, it would also be wrong to assume that every person who travels *by car* travels in a car that belongs to them, so "their car" isn't really appropriate anyway.

Comment: There is no such context to make "car" acceptable here. Why does it sound jarring in the first place? And why is it "missing" a determiner? What rule of grammar necessitates it to have one in this sentence?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I don't find "using car" just "jarring," but completely unacceptable in all imaginable circumstances.

Comment: @theonlygusti You're quite wrong, there *is* a context, it is pretty exclusive but it could well apply to the OP's example, depending on the context which they have not provided. I had already alluded to it in my answer but I've added in a specific example.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Then your imagination is limited.

Comment: Such a context can exist, but the example in my quesiton is not embedded in one

Comment: Why is the word 'car' in the quesiton "missing" a determiner? What rule of grammar necessitates it to have one in this sentence?

Comment: @theonlygusti "Car" is a common noun, it is not the name of something unique, so it would normally have either an article (eg "the car") or a determiner (eg "my car"). If I understand your question correctly - you have found a sentence where 'car' has neither of these, and you are being told that is wrong. In most cases, it would be wrong, and if your example if part of your English learning course then the answer is probably that it is wrong. My answer explains one possible reason why it *could* be right. Take it or leave it.

Comment: In your example the *car* is not a **car**.  It is, instead, an **answer**. Your example works for any and all nouns when the noun ceases to be itself and becomes an answer.  With due respect, I don't think it works.  *Using car* does not work.  Answering a question with the word *car* does.

Comment: @Astralbee this most recent comment seems like the actual answer to my question. "common noun... would normally have either an article (eg "the car") or a determiner". The wikipedia page English determiners affirms that.